# Is cloning selectlist options recommended as an optimization strategy?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a large form consisting of 'rows' of sets of values to choose from.

Pseudocode to help visualize:

```
<row id=1> <checkbox> <date> <text> <select>
<row id=2> <checkbox> <date> <text> <select>
```

etc.

Upon submit, a controller processes all values for the checked rows. It is all ASP.NET Core MVC, no client-side scripting.

I populate the form with tag helpers. In case of the selectlists, I use `<select asp-for="someEntityId" asp-items="Model.SomeEntityList">`.

It all works fine but since I have a lot of 'rows', the resulting page is pretty large.

One of the optimization strategies I came up with is not to populate all the select elements with all options since most of them will have a default value that remains unchanged. I could put in some jQuery to populate them dynamically, for example by cloning the first 'row's' values.

Web development is new to me so before I get my hands dirty (I can already see a few challenges ahead) I would like to ask: is this a viable and/or recommended strategy?

Comment: Roughly how many rows and how many options per row? And are you trying to optimize client side or server side?

Comment: The major problem with that is model binding - the TagHelpers set the selected option, and therefore the correct option will not be set

Comment: @charlietfl 500 / 10. Trying to optimize client-side

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, that is one of the challenges I anticipated

Comment: 500 rows is probably unrealistic to edit in the view at one time - perhaps you need to reconsider the design

Comment: @StephenMuecke I agree. They are organized as an open-ended tree structure, so the end-user doesn't see 500 rows unless he drills down. And they are organized into groups.

Comment: Then why not load just what the user needs on demand (by using ajax when a node is expanded)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have considered that. But I do not know how to retain model binding in that case. It quickly gets pretty complex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177458/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-arno-van-boven).

Comment: For simplification to get started could wrap groups in fieldsets and add a form wizard script to act as pagination. Majority of fieldsets would be hidden on page load

Comment: @charlietfl tx for the suggestion, I have that in place already, just didn't mention it because it wasn't relevant to the original question

Comment: @charlietfl the 'rows' I spoke of are organized as a tree-structure and segmented using smart wizard; the user does not see 500 rows.